# How to export xlsx files in SAS

Tags: sas, export-to-excel

The following two exports, will give an error on my machine (in both SAS base and SAS Enterprise Guide):

```
proc  export data=  sashelp.shoes
            outfile= " D:\SAS\myfile.xlsx"
            dbms=xlsx replace;
       sheet="Shoes";
run;

proc  export data=  sashelp.class
            outfile= " D:\SAS\myfile.xlsx"
            dbms=excelcs replace;
       sheet="Class";
run;
```

as these exports produce the following errors respectively:

```
ERROR: DBMS type XLSX not valid for export.
ERROR: DBMS type EXCELCS not valid for export.
```

By browsing the internet I think that the problem is caused by exporting the file from a 64-bit SAS version to a 32-bit Excel version.

I downloaded and installed `pcfilesrv__931401__win__en__web__1.zip` from the [SAS Support website](https://support.sas.com/downloads/package.htm?pid=893) and hoped it would solve the problem, however the errors still occur.

Anybody with another idea?

Specs:

Windows 64-bit Operating System

SAS Enterprice Guide 5.1 (64-bit)

SAS Base 9.3 (64-bit)

Excel 2013 (32-bit)

**EDIT:**
@Grinvydas Kareiva mentioned in his answer that I needed the "SAS/Access Interface to PC Files". This installation wizard after running `setup.exe` in the zip file I downloaded from the SAS Support website (see above). 
[image: Install Wizard]

However, when I run `proc setinit`, it doesn't show up anywhere (changed site number and name manually):

```
Site name:    'xxxxxxx'.
Site number:  xxxxxx.
Expiration:   01SEP2017.
Grace Period:  62 days (ending 02NOV2017).
Warning Period: 31 days (ending 03DEC2017).
System birthday:   01NOV2016.
Operating System:   WX64_WKS.
Product expiration dates:
---Base SAS Software                                                                                    01SEP2017  
---SAS/STAT                                                                                             01SEP2017  
---SAS/GRAPH                                                                                            01SEP2017  
---SAS Enterprise Guide                                                                                 01SEP2017  
---SAS Workspace Server for Local Access                                                                01SEP2017
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Would  DBMS=XLS work? (I don't think it requires any add-ons, but not sure.)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. [csv on the other hand works, however I need it to be a xlsx due to automatic process after SAS which expect xlsx]. The more I read about it, it looks to me like it is a bug in SAS 9.3 64-bit, which can't export anything to 32-bit Office products. So my guess is that all exports with an 'Office product extension' will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to have licensed "SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files".
You can check that in the log after submitting

```
proc setinit;
run;
```

One of these should work if you have that interface

```
dbms=excel or dbms=xlsx
```

Comment: Well I guess that is where it goes wrong. I don't see "SAS/Access Interface to PC Files" when I run `proc setinit`. However, the zip file I mentioned should install this SAS/Access Interface, right?

Comment: You need to purchase a licence for the extra module and apply the licence update as well as physically installing it. Contact SAS support.

Comment: Until you obtain a valid license, this macro maybe a valid workaround. http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/A_Poor/Rich_SAS_Users_Proc_Export

Comment: @Reeza Thanks for the tip! I will definitely check it out!

Comment: @user667489 So if I understand correctly. I need to buy a license in order to make an xlsx export work from the code. In SAS EG, I can also manually export to xlsx which does work. (Strange IMO.) I don't think my supervisor wants to pay for this, unfortunately. I will check out Reeza's tip and possibly contact SAS Support.

Comment: That's a not very pleasant part of using SAS, you have to pay for things that might look very basic and standard :)

Comment: @GrinvydasKareiva True but it also allows them to drop prices if you only operate with access to a server. It's like paying to check a bag at the airport. And the latest versions don't have this restriction. .

Answer (score 0):

In SAS 9.4 TS1M1 and later, you can use `ods excel` to export actual xlsx files without the license for ACCESS to PC FILES.  In SAS 9.3, this functionality isn't available.

Comment: Too bad, I have SAS 9.3 TS1M2

Answer (score 0):

```
use the below code to export excel or csv file 
/*import the .xlsx or csv file */
FILENAME REFFILE '/<path to file>/Statistic_Details.xlsx';

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE=REFFILE
    DBMS=XLSX
    OUT=libref.Statistic_Details;
    GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;

PROC CONTENTS DATA=libref.Statistic_Details; RUN;
```

Comment: Why does this answer the question? What did you do? Can you explain, please? That would make it easier to understand. Thanks!